# How to use images from two datasets as input in a CNN classification model?

Tags: python, keras

These are my two datasets, each consisting of images with dimensions 512*512 and a channel size of 1.

```
batch_size =1
img_height = 512
img_width = 512

Xray_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
Xray_input,
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size,
color_mode="grayscale")

Mask_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
Mask_input,
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size,
color_mode="grayscale")
```

Next, I intend to use these two datasets as input to my model. After applying a convolutional operation to each dataset separately, I plan to concatenate them. The concatenated output will then undergo a series of convolutional layers and fully connected layers, ultimately leading to classification into five categories.

```
def Classification(nb_classes, input_shape):
    input_tensor_Xray = Input(shape=input_shape)
    input_tensor_mask = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # 將兩個輸入各自做3*3*1conv
    conv_Xray = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conv_Xray')(input_tensor_Xray)
    conv_mask = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conv_mask')(input_tensor_mask)
# 拼接两个卷积层的输出
    concatenated = layers.concatenate([conv_Xray, conv_mask], axis=-1)
    # 7*7conv
    x0 = Conv2D(64, (7,7), activation='relu', padding='same',name='block1_conv0')(concatenated)
..... 
 model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_Xray, input_tensor_mask], outputs=output_tensor)

    # 定义模型
#    model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_Xray, input_tensor_mask], outputs=dense2)
    return model

model=Classification(5, (img_width, img_height,1))
model.summary()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rrE1.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxlLW.jpg)

The issue I'm encountering is that when using model.fit, I am unable to train the model with both datasets as inputs. Below is my code.

```
history = model.fit(
    [Xray_train_ds,Mask_train_ds],
    validation_data=([Xray_val_ds,Mask_val_ds]),
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[checkpoint] 
)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Later, I found information online suggesting that the issue might be related to tensors. Therefore, I made some modifications.

> 

```
def generator_fn(ds):
    for images, labels in ds:
        yield images

Xray_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: generator_fn(Xray_train_ds),
    output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, img_height, img_width, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
)

Mask_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: generator_fn(Mask_train_ds),
    output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, img_height, img_width, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
)





# 轉換為 tf.data.Dataset
Xray_test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: generator_fn(Xray_test_ds),
    output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, img_height, img_width, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
)

Mask_test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: generator_fn(Mask_test_ds),
    output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, img_height, img_width, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
)

# 合併兩個資料集
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Xray_train_dataset, Mask_train_dataset))
combined_dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Xray_test_dataset, Mask_test_dataset))

history = model.fit(
    combined_dataset,
    validation_data=combined_dataset2,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],

)
```

But the error still persists.

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 512, 512, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

Please help me make modifications or suggest alternative ways to use different input sets?